# openssl pkcs12 set password from command line

Tags: bash, openssl, pfx

I have a bash command like this

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ~/certificate.pfx -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/exapmle.com/privkey.pem -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/exapmle.com/cert.pem -certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/exapmle.com/chain.pem
```

and now I'll be asked to enter a password to encrypt the .pfx file. So is there any  way to set a password from command line to don't doing this operation manually every time?

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs12.html). It describes `-passout arg` for that purpose, or you can use `-password arg` in your case as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resulting command is

```
openssl pkcs12 -password pass:your_password -export -out ~/certificate.pfx -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/exapmle.com/privkey.pem -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/exapmle.com/cert.pem -certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/exapmle.com/chain.pem
```